# Insert or update in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

What would be the best way to set this query? i can't seem to find any documentation on an actual insert or update that works, I'm hoping to do it via the Eloquent model but can't seem to get it working

any help would be appreciated.

```
DB::table('questions')->insert([
    'marital_status' => $request->marital_status,
    'job_title' => $request->job_Title,
    'industry' => $request->industry,
    'occupation' => $request->occupation,
    'paye' => $request->paye,
    'self_employed' => $request->self_employed,
    'child_benefit' => $request->child_benefit,
    'work_home' => $request->work_home,
    'own_transport' => $request->own_transport,
    'company_vehicle' => $request->company_vehicle,
    'annual_income' => $request->annual_income,
    'pay_memberships' => $request->pay_memberships,
    'income_benefits' => $request->income_benefits,
    'printer' => $request->printer,
    'contact' => $request->contact,
    'share' => $request->share,
    'terms' => $request->terms,
    'user_id' => $user
]);
```

here is my Model for Questions

```
<?php
namespace App;

class Questions extends Model
{
     protected $fillable = [
         'marital_status',
         'job_title',
         'industry',
         'occupation',
         'paye',
         'self_employed',
         'child_benefit',
         'work_home',
         'own_transport',
         'company_vehicle',
         'annual_income',
         'pay_memberships',
         'income_benefits',
         'printer',
         'contact',
         'share',
         'terms',
         'user_id'
    ];

    public function users(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\User');

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Eloquent with [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment):

```
Question::updateOrCreate($request->all()->put('user_id', $user));
```

Or:

```
$question = Question::firstOrNew('some_id', $someId);
$question->fill($request->all()->put('user_id', $user))->save();
```

Don't forget to fill `$fillable` array with all properties you want to persist:

```
class Question extends Model
{
      protected $fillable = [
            'marital_status', 
            'job_title',
            'industry',
            'occupation',
            'paye',
            'self_employed',
            'child_benefit',
            'work_home',
            'own_transport',
            'company_vehicle',
            'annual_income',
            'pay_memberships',
            'income_benefits',
            'printer',
            'contact',
            'share',
            'terms',
            'user_id'
      ]
```

**Update**

If `put()` method doesn't work for some reason, try this:

```
$request->merge(['user_id' => $user]);
```

And then just use `$request->all()`

Or:

```
$requestData = $request->all();
$requestData['user_id'] = $user;
```

And then use `$requestData`

Comment: I'm trying to use the eloquent way however whenever i get the error 'Call to undefined method App\questions::updateOrCreate()' and not too sure why

Comment: It should be `App\Question::`. Check if you have this model.

Comment: I'm trying both ways now,  for the first way, i get this error 'Call to a member function put() on array'. The second is giving me loads of issues so for so i'm trying to get the first way to work.

Comment: @TomFisher, I can't test it right now, but this should work. If it still doesn't, try one of two solutions from updated answer.

Comment: Instead of defining every property you want to me mass assignable, you can also use the opposite way and protect everything that shouldn't be mass assignable with `protected $quarded = ['id'];`. Also Tom Fisher has to be sure his field name in the form match the ones in the database.